# Running DroneKit Air on my 3DR Solo

Tags: dronekit-python

The getting started documentation I can find is helpful in loading up a dronekit script in the simulator, but I can't figure out how to then translate the process to transfer scripts onto my Solo for real world execution.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding somewhere.  Please help, and thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: I've put my computer on the wifi network named SoloLink, and nmap reveals open ssh ports on 10.1.1.10 and 10.1.1.1.  My guess is one is the controller and the other is the drone.  Can't seem to guess the ssh login tho :)

Answer (score 1):

Root password for both 3drobotics Solo and Artoo is "TjSDBkAu" aka Tj (Tijuana) SD (San Diego) Bk (Back) A (At) u (You).

./src/com/o3dr/solo/android/service/artoo/ArtooLinkManager.java:  private static final SshConnection sshLink = new SshConnection("10.1.1.1", "root", "TjSDBkAu");

./src/com/o3dr/solo/android/service/sololink/SoloLinkManager.java:  private static final SshConnection sshLink = new SshConnection(getSoloLinkIp(), "root", "TjSDBkAu");

./src/com/o3dr/solo/android/service/update/UpdateService.java:  public static final String SSH_PASSWORD = "TjSDBkAu";

Answer (score 0):

We are working on a new firmware release together with some guides/docs that will allow for a better development experience, right now all you can do is scp your files, add them to .mavinit.scr on home directory and kill the mavproxy process to make sure it reloads this configuration.

That said, I would be very careful in flying with untested code as an exception might cause other parts of Solo to fail and cause you to crash, please test thoroughly before flying.